# Solving Limits with L'Hospital's Rules

Tags: calculus, limits

I am having difficulties solving this limit. I was given the question and equation:

*Try using L’Hospital’s Rules to evaluate the follwing limit:*

$$\lim\limits_{u \to \infty } \frac{u}{\sqrt{u^2 +1}}$$

How do you solve this with L'Hospital's rules? Do you solve this with them?

Comment: The limit is as $x \to \infty$ but the function $\tfrac{u}{\sqrt{u^2+1}}$ depends on $u$ not $x$. Are you sure this isn't a typo?

Comment: @asdasdfasdf I understood that you wanted to see this limit using LH, but since a sound answer was already posted, I hope that you don't mind my having shown the solution using a non-LH way forward.

Comment: @asdfasdfasdf Please avoid using L'Hôpitals Rule :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are there any limit questions which are easier to solve using methods other than l'Hopital's Rule?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1534296/are-there-any-limit-questions-which-are-easier-to-solve-using-methods-other-than)

Comment: You can use l'Hopital's rule.  You would probably be better off in this case just using the epsilon-N definition, though.

Answer (score 8):

$\color{red}{\text{Method 1}}$: Using L-Hospital's Rule for $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ form as follows $$\lim_{u\to \infty}\frac{u}{\sqrt{u^2+1}}$$ $$=\lim_{u\to \infty}\frac{\frac{d(u)}{du}}{\frac{d}{du}(\sqrt{u^2+1})}$$ 
 $$=\lim_{u\to \infty}\frac{1}{\frac{2u}{2\sqrt{u^2+1}}}$$ $$=\lim_{u\to \infty}\frac{\sqrt{u^2+1}}{u}$$ $$=\lim_{u\to \infty}\sqrt{\frac{u^2}{u^2}+\frac{1}{u^2}}$$ $$=\lim_{u\to \infty}\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{1}{u}\right)^2}$$ Let, $u=\frac{1}{t}\implies t\to 0 \ as \ u\to \infty$ $$=\lim_{t\to 0}\sqrt{1+(t)^2}$$ $$=\sqrt{1+0}=1$$

$\color{red}{\text{Method 2}}$: Without using L-Hospital's rule

Given, $$\lim_{u\to \infty}\frac{u}{\sqrt{u^2+1}}$$ 
Let, $u=\frac{1}{t}\implies t\to 0 \ as \ u\to \infty$, hence we have  $$\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\frac{1}{t}}{\sqrt{\left(\frac{1}{t}\right)^2+1}}$$ $$=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+t^2}}$$ $$=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+0}}=1$$

Comment: what is this method of solving limits called? (representing $u$ as a rational function $\frac {1}{t}$) I'd like to look further into it. Thank you!

Comment: in fact, you  may simply call it substitution.

Comment: How do you go from $\lim\limits_{u \to \infty} \frac{\sqrt{u^2 +1}}{u}$ to $\lim\limits_{u \to \infty} \sqrt{1+(\frac{1}{u})^2 }$ ??

Comment: Take, $u$ inside the square root. like $u=\sqrt{u^2}$

Comment: In your method 1, could you not have taken a shortcut at your fourth line, having shown that $\lim_{u\rightarrow\infty} f(u) = \lim_{u\rightarrow\infty} 1/f(u)$?

Comment: @Eric Towers, yes you are absolutely right, you may let $\frac{1}{u}=t$ & proceed. For the sake of clarity, I have edited the answer.

Answer (score 7):

@Harish Chandra Rajpoot has already presented two very sound approaches including use of the requested L'Hopital's Rule

So, I thought that it would be instructive to show another way forward that can be used broadly.

Here, we use asymptotic analysis and write

$$\begin{align}
\frac{u}{\sqrt{u^2+1}}&=(1+u^{-2})^{-1/2}\\\\
&=1-\frac{1}{2}u^{-2}+O(u^{-4})\\\\
&\to 1\,\,\text{as}\,\,u\to \infty
\end{align}$$

... and we are done! Fast and efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Wow, these answers. I can't believe this. This is such a straightforward limit!

$$\lim_{u\to \infty } \frac{u}{\sqrt{u^2+1}}$$$$ = \lim_{u\to \infty } \frac{u}{\sqrt{u^2(1+\frac{1}{u^2})}} $$$$= \lim_{u\to \infty } \frac{u}{u \sqrt{1+\frac{1}{u^2}}} $$$$= \lim_{u\to \infty } \frac{1}{ \sqrt{1+\frac{1}{u^2}}}$$$$ = 1$$

Boom! No substitutions, no l'Hôpital's rule.

Comment: The only thing that you miss is that the OP himself explicitly asked for a solution based upon l'Hospital's theorem, therefore your post cannot be considered an answer.

Comment: @jyerkimenon And I concede that my way forward is overkill.  Buy note that I preceeded it by stating I was presenting a way forward that has broad use (i.e., asymptotic analysis).

Answer (score 0):

Use l'hopital's rule $$\lim\limits_{u \to \infty } \frac{u}{\sqrt{u^2 +1}}=\lim\limits_{u \to \infty } \frac{1}{\frac{2u}{2\sqrt{u^2 +1}}}$$
$$=\lim\limits_{u \to \infty } \frac{\sqrt{u^2 +1}}{u}$$
$$=\lim\limits_{u \to \infty } \sqrt{1+\frac1{u^2}}=1$$

Answer (score -1):

$$\lim\limits_{u \to \infty } \frac{u}{\sqrt{u^2 +1}} = \lim\limits_{u \to \infty } \frac{\color{red}{\sqrt{u^2}}}{\sqrt{u^2 +1}}$$

because

> while $\sqrt{u^2} = |u|$, we may assume $u \ge 0$ since $u \to \infty$ so $\sqrt{u^2} = |u| = u$

After that we have

> $$ \lim\limits_{u \to \infty } \frac{\color{red}{\sqrt{u^2}}}{\sqrt{u^2 +1}} = \lim\limits_{u \to \infty } \sqrt{\frac{u^2}{u^2 +1}} =  \sqrt{\lim\limits_{u \to \infty }\frac{u^2}{u^2 +1}}$$

Actually

> It may help to note that for large $u$, $\sqrt{u^2 + 1}$ behaves like $\sqrt{u^2}$