# Evaluating $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow0} \frac{e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}-\cos x}{x^3\sin x}$

Tags: limits

I'm trying to evaluate $$\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow0}  \frac{e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}-\cos x}{x^3\sin x}.$$

I can see the $\frac{0}{0}$ *form*, so I'll use *L'Hôpital's rule*. However, I'll eliminate the *sine* function in the denominator by multiplying the numerator and denominator by $x$. We know

$$\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow0}  \frac{x}{\sin x} = 1.$$

The problem reduces to

$$\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow0}  \frac{e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}-\cos x}{x^4}.$$

Now I'll use L'Hôpital's rule. The problem now becomes

$$\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow0}  \frac{e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}(-x)+\sin x}{4x^3}.$$

I don't know how to proceed from here onwards. Using L'Hôpital's rule any more complicates the problem. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you allowed to use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series?

Comment: Unpopular(?) opinion: L'Hôpital's rule is a stupid rule.

Comment: @zkutch Yes, I'd like to know how to solve it that way.

Comment: @nejimban I'd appreciate learning any other method for solving such problems.

Comment: Using Taylor series is how I would prove L'Hôpital's rule and is much more robust. See: $\mathrm e^{-\frac{x^2}2}=1-\frac{x^2}2+\frac{x^4}8+o(x^4)$ and $\cos(x)=1-\frac{x^2}2+\frac{x^4}{24}+o(x^4)$ gives you $\mathrm e^{-\frac{x^2}2}-\cos(x)\sim\frac{x^4}{12}$. Now $\sin(x)\sim x$ so $$\frac{\mathrm e^{-\frac{x^2}2}-\cos(x)}{x^3\sin(x)}\sim\frac{\frac{x^4}{12}}{x^3\cdot x}=\frac1{12}.$$

Comment: @nejimban I wish I could upvote your comments more than once.

Comment: @nejimban Don't know why, but I also have an aversion to L'H rule. It's overrated

Comment: @nejimban: I totally agree. There is nothing you can do with L'Hopital that cannot be done better using asymptotic expansion, as demonstrated in the posts linked from my profile.

Comment: Note that you should say that your asymptotic statements are **under the limiting condition** of "as $x→0$".

Comment: @SineoftheTime: You might also be interested to look at the posts I mentioned, as well as [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1536437/21820).

Comment: @user21820 Interesting reads, thank you! Even though L'Hôpital was a French mathematician, I find it amusing that his rule is generally ignored in French schools and universities (we prefer to emphasize on asymptotic expansions and Taylor series) but remains quite popular abroad.

Comment: @nejimban: Hahaha I didn't know that! Thanks for the interesting note!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following steps use De l'Hopital rule.

$$\lim _{x\to 0}\left(\frac{e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}-\cos \left(x\right)}{x^3\sin \left(x\right)}\right)=\lim _{x\to \:0}\left(\frac{-e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}x+\sin \left(x\right)}{3x^2\sin \left(x\right)+\cos \left(x\right)x^3}\right)=\lim _{x\to \:0}\left(\frac{e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}x^2-e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}+\cos \left(x\right)}{-x^3\sin \left(x\right)+6x^2\cos \left(x\right)+6x\sin \left(x\right)}\right)$$
$$=\lim _{x\to  0}\left(\frac{-e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}x^3+3e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}x-\sin \left(x\right)}{-x^3\cos \left(x\right)-9x^2\sin \left(x\right)+18x\cos \left(x\right)+6\sin \left(x\right)}\right)=\lim _{x\to 0}\left(\frac{e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}x^4-6e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}x^2+3e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}-\cos \left(x\right)}{x^3\sin \left(x\right)-12x^2\cos \left(x\right)-36x\sin \left(x\right)+24\cos \left(x\right)}\right)$$
$$=\frac{e^{-\frac{0^2}{2}}\cdot  0^4-6e^{-\frac{0^2}{2}}\cdot  0^2+3e^{-\frac{0^2}{2}}-\cos \left(0\right)}{0^3\sin \left(0\right)-12\cdot  0^2\cos \left(0\right)-36\cdot  0\cdot \sin \left(0\right)+24\cos \left(0\right)}=\frac 1{12}. \square$$

Answer (score 0):

An elegant way to solve this problem, as suggested by @nejimban, is to use the Taylor series.

$\mathrm e^{-\frac{x^2}2}$ can be written as    $$1-\frac{x^2}2+\frac{x^4}8+o(x^4)$$

whereas $\cos(x)$ can be written as $$1-\frac{x^2}2+\frac{x^4}{24}+o(x^4)$$

Now on subtracting,

$$\mathrm e^{-\frac{x^2}2}-\cos(x)\sim\frac{x^4}{12} \;\;\text{ and }\;\; \sin(x)\sim x$$

On substituting these values in the original limit-

$$\frac{\mathrm e^{-\frac{x^2}2}-\cos(x)}{x^3\sin(x)}\sim\frac{\frac{x^4}{12}}{x^3\cdot x}=\frac1{12}.$$